# Assigning values dynamically in a classic ASP FOR EACH loop

Tags: arrays, loops, asp-classic, foreach

I'm trying to assign a value to a series of variables inside a FOR EACH loop, but keep getting a "Type mismatch" error.

```
personOrder = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15" 'order items displayed onscreen

personArray = split(personOrder, ",")

For each i in personArray
    imageArray(i) = objContentXML.selectSingleNode("/page/profile" & i & "/image").text
Next
```

Note: I've made the var personOrder a list because in the future items might change order.

I think there's a problem with assigning array values in a FOR EACH loop. Annoyingly it works fine in a FOR loop, but I'm trying to future proof my code.

Apologies if this question is too stupid. I'm returning after 9 months of nappies and burping to the world of code (less nappies, more burping).

Comment: BTW, consider not using node names like `<profile1>`, `<profile2>`.  This is poor form for XML.  The number suffixes are part of your data.  Instead use  `<profile ID="1">` and `<profile ID="2">`.  Your selection xpath becomes `"/page/profile[@ID=""" & i & """]/image".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On which statement do you get this error? I can execute the following code without any error messages:

```
personOrder = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15" 'order items displayed onscreen

personArray = split(personOrder, ",")

dim imageArray
redim imageArray(uBound(personArray) + 1)

For each i in personArray
    imageArray(i) = i
Next
```

You must create an array first and declare the number of items you want to put in it (use redim to change the dimensions).

I replaced your objectContentXML with a simple statement, for testing purposes.

Comment: Ah thanks. I worked out that I needed to create the array first just after I posted the question, but I am currently fighting the error "Expected integer constant" from the line `dim imageArray(uBound(personArray) + 1)`  

I've also edited the code slightly, because the position in the array was being set incorrectly.  
`x=1  
For each i in personArray  
    imageArray(x) = i  
    x=x+1  
Next`

Comment: Try the following: `dim imageArray` and then right after that `redim imageArray(uBound(personArray) + 1)`. I cannot reproduce your error, but the error whines that it needs a constant integer (1,2,3,4,etc), not the result of a statement (1+2).